# Why react doesn't call render when state is changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

I have problem with automatically re-rendering view, when state is changed.
State has been changed, but `render()` is not called. But when I call `this.forceUpdate()`, everything is ok, but I think that's not the best solution.
Can someone help me with that ?

```
class TODOItems extends React.Component {

constructor() {
    super();

    this.loadItems();
}

loadItems() {
    this.state = {
        todos: Store.getItems()
    };
}

componentDidMount(){
    //this loads new items to this.state.todos, but render() is not called
    Store.addChangeListener(() => { this.loadItems(); this.forceUpdate(); });
}

componentWillUnmount(){
    Store.removeChangeListener(() => { this.loadItems(); });
}

render() {

    console.log("data changed, re-render");
    //...
}}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be using `this.state = {};` (like in your `loadItems()` method) from the constructor when you are declaring the initial state. When you want to update the items, use `this.setState({})`. For example:

```
constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        todos: Store.getItems()
    };
}

reloadItems() {
    this.setState({
        todos: Store.getItems()
    });
}
```

and update your `componentDidMount`:

```
Store.addChangeListener(() => { this.reloadItems(); });
```

Comment: `this.state` should never be mutated directly.

Comment: @JCD My mistake, I'm coming from React Native where `this.state = {}` can be used to declare the initial state from the constructor.

Comment: @JCD Actually, according to the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html) this is perfectly legitimate, or at least it's used there (See under ES6 Classes in the 2nd code block)

Comment: yeah when using ES6 classes, you assign state directly in the constructor.  Once the constructor completes, never mutate it directly but instead use `setState`

Comment: Thanks guys, I thought that when I set this in the constructor as an ordinary object, so it sets(changes) the same way everywhere.

Answer (score 7):

You sholdn't mutate `this.state` directly. You should use `this.setState` method.

Change `loadItems`:

```
loadItems() {
    this.setState({
        todos: Store.getItems()
    });
}
```

[More in react docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate)

Answer (score 0):

In your component, whenever you directly manipulate state you need to use the following:

```
this.setState({});
```

Complete code:

```
class TODOItems extends React.Component {

constructor() {
    super();

    this.loadItems();
}

loadItems() {
  let newState = Store.getItems();
    this.setState = {

        todos: newState
    };
}

componentDidMount(){
    //this loads new items to this.state.todos, but render() is not called
    Store.addChangeListener(() => { this.loadItems(); this.forceUpdate(); });
}

componentWillUnmount(){
    Store.removeChangeListener(() => { this.loadItems(); });
}

render() {

    console.log("data changed, re-render");
    //...
}}
```