# react tutorial: state not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing the [React Tic Tac Toe starter tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html) and having problems in the beginning....

Each Square should display its state.value and have a onClick method which sets the state to 'X'. The GUI should be updating when clicked but it's not... I can't spot the error in my code, can you?

```
class Square extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {value: null};
  }
  setState(s) {this.state = s;}
  render() {
    return (
      <button className="square" onClick={() => this.setState({value:'X'})}>
        {this.state.value}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class Board extends React.Component {
  renderSquare(i) {
    return <Square value={i}/>;
  }
  render() {
    const status = 'Next player: X';
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="status">{status}</div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(0)}
          {this.renderSquare(1)}
          {this.renderSquare(2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(3)}
          {this.renderSquare(4)}
          {this.renderSquare(5)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(6)}
          {this.renderSquare(7)}
          {this.renderSquare(8)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Game extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="game">
        <div className="game-board">
          <Board />
        </div>
        <div className="game-info">
          <div>{/* status */}</div>
          <ol>{/* TODO */}</ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(
  <Game />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);

function calculateWinner(squares) {
  const lines = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6],
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
    if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
      return squares[a];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Why are you overriding state itself. You should update property inside state. Try `this.setState({value: s})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove line above render() method, your setState() definition. You don't have to create this method, it's already created for you.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. So getter and setter on `state` property is automatically set. Does this apply for other properties than `state`? And is this a feature of React or just native ES6?

Comment: @Rajesh why it should be a comment when it's a solution for his problem?

Comment: @olefrank No, it's only for `state` variable. When you call `setState` React knows that component should be re-rendered. Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36185577/why-react-doesnt-call-render-when-state-is-changed I had similar problem

Comment: `setState` can be overridden. But issue is OP is replacing state it self. So when something changes, react has no way of detecting the changes as entire reference is replaced.

Answer (score 1):

`setState` is an internal method provided by the **react library** itself. There is not need for you to override it in your code.

```js
class Square extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {value: null};
  }
  render() {
    return ( 
      <button className="square" onClick={() => this.setState({value:'X'})}>
        {this.state.value}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class Board extends React.Component {
  renderSquare(i) {
    return <Square value={i}/>;
  }
  render() {
    const status = 'Next player: X';
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="status">{status}</div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(0)}
          {this.renderSquare(1)}
          {this.renderSquare(2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(3)}
          {this.renderSquare(4)}
          {this.renderSquare(5)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(6)}
          {this.renderSquare(7)}
          {this.renderSquare(8)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Game extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="game">
        <div className="game-board">
          <Board />
        </div>
        <div className="game-info">
          <div>{/* status */}</div>
          <ol>{/* TODO */}</ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(
  <Game />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);

function calculateWinner(squares) {
  const lines = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6],
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
    if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
      return squares[a];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```